# Annotations from database to Ti.map Appcelerator

Tags: database, dictionary, annotations, titanium, appcelerator

I'm trying to create an array which pushes values from a local database into an annotation, in Titanium. The annotation doesn't respond to the value of my database. I think I'm doing a school boy error somewhere but I have been staring myself blind for a while now. Can anyone help me?
Much appreciated!
Cheers.

function localdb(){

```
var db = Ti.Database.install('/my_db/annotations.sqlite', 'Annos');
var row = db.execute('select title, latitude, longitude, type from annotations ');
places = [];

while (row.isValidRow()){
       var annotation = Titanium.Map.createAnnotation({
               latitude:row.fieldByName('latitude'),
               longitude:row.fieldByName('longitude'),
               title:row.fieldByName('title'),
               subtitle:row.fieldByName('type'),
               animate:true,
               pincolor: Titanium.Map.ANNOTATION_GREEN
    });

       places.push(annotation);
       mapview.addAnnotation(annotation);
       row.next();

}

mapview.annotations = places;
db.close();
```

}

```
   var mapview = Titanium.Map.createView({
   mapType: Titanium.Map.STANDARD_TYPE,
   height: '100%',
   animate:true,
   regionFit:true,
   userLocation:true,
```

});

localdb();

win.add(mapview);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the addAnnotations method passing the array of annotations you created
http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Map.View-method-addAnnotations

```
var places = [];

while (row.isValidRow()){
   var annotation = Titanium.Map.createAnnotation({
           latitude:row.fieldByName('latitude'),
           longitude:row.fieldByName('longitude'),
           title:row.fieldByName('title'),
           subtitle:row.fieldByName('type'),
           animate:true,
           pincolor: Titanium.Map.ANNOTATION_GREEN
});
   places.push(annotation);
   row.next();
}
// optional mapview.removeAllAnnotations();
mapview.addAnnotations(places);
```

Comment: Thanks mate, much appreciated. I solved it by adding mapview.annotations = places; to inside the while loop and deleting the mapview.annotations = places; from the function entirely. Also some good practice to add a row.close(); before end of function I was told...:)